# Does two different programs load shared library function at same physical memory location

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, shared-libraries, shared-memory

I am using OpenSSL shared library to do simple encryption using AES_cbc_encrypt() function. I want to know if I use this AES_cbc_encrypt() function from two different program, will both program point to the same location in Physical memory for this AES_cbc_encrypt() function?

My other questions are

1 > If I use shared library  will it be automatically pointed to same physical memory location by all programs where it is being used ?

Or

2 > Do I need to follow some other technique to force the programs to load the shared library at the same physical memory in RAM. ( I don't think so it is true then there is no use of shared memory concept. It's my understanding).

3 >
How to check whether both program load the shared library function at same physical location.

4> I calculate the location (virtual address) of function in both program by using  (& AES_cbc_encrypt) , then using tool [capture](http://www.eqware.net/Articles/CapturingProcessMemoryUsageUnderLinux/index.html), I convert this virtual address (VPN) to Physical address (PFN). But, I don't know how to calculate physical address from this VPN, PFN info. So not able to compare further . Any clue ?

For example my virtual address is

```
=0x400cb0
```

Virtual address

Starting address- end address

```
 00400000-00402000
```

Physical Page

```
 : A600000000036E26

 : A60000000008A4C3
```

In my system

****Virtual address space : 48 bit**

**Physical address space : 36 bit****

I am using GCC under Linux. Any help or pointer/link will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why you care about physical RAM. Leave its management to the kernel, it does that very well.

Comment: **Why do you ask** ? It looks like you misunderstand [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

Answer (score 2):

Read Drepper's paper [How To Write Shared Libraries](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf).

Shared libraries use [position independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) (to minimize [relocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29)). They are [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)-ed by the dynamic linker [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html). Linux [processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) have their [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) in [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) managed by the [linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) thru [paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging).

The kernel will generally share read segments (e.g. the [text segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_segment)) of shared libraries (so their pages use indeed the same RAM for different processes).

You could use `/proc/self/maps` (or `/proc/1234/maps` for the process of pid 1234) to find out the memory mapping of a process. See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

You should not care about (and application don't *directly* see) RAM pages. Only the kernel manage physical [RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM) (and it can move pages in the RAM, page out them to disk, etc.) thru the [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit).

See also [mincore(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mincore.2.html) & [mlock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html). Read also about [OOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory) & [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29) & [swap space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swap_space).

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) !

Comment: @ Basile ,Thanks for answering. I am trying to verify whether both program points to same physical location in RAM, but unable to do . any clue in that direction. I read from other place where it mentioned (theoretically) both program points to same location.  I want to check programatically .

Comment: You should not care. The RAM is managed by the kernel, application code don't see it. Applications only see virtual memory.

Comment: @bholanath: In general you cannot find that mapping.  The physical mapping may change from instant to instant.

Comment: yes, I know. But as I said , just to verify (out of curiosity) whether both program point to same physical location in RAM , I first calculate virtual address in program , then convert that virtual address to physical address. But I am getting two different physical address. Is my conversion method wrong ? I am using above mention tool code ( VPN to PFN).

Comment: In my system I disable ASLR also.

Comment: yes, I am actually use /proc/pid/maps and /proc/pid/pagemap to calculate VPN to PFN mapping.

Comment: You question don't have any sense. The kernel is free to page out RAM pages at will (but it often don't do that, except under stress). By the time you have queried the kernel, the information could be stale.... So it has no sense to application code.

Comment: Is there any way to prove both program points to same memory location. I need this info as my next task is based on this info. I tried to flush out the memory content ( shared memory ) from cache, then figure out whether it is accessed by other process or not, but no impact at all. So either they are not pointing to same cache/main memory or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: In short no, but very likely both processes are often using the same RAM pages to share read only code segments. But you really should not care, and I believe your question does not have any sense (the kernel could change paging at any instant)

Comment: If I use clflush(address) , that will flush out content from all levels of cache. Now If other program access the shared library then content may be loaded into that address. So next time if I try to access address which I already flushed earlier , I will get the data from cache ( no need to access main memory as other program already accessed it and so loaded into cache). I am expecting this for my program , but I am not getting . that's the reason I just want to figure out how to make sure they are pointing to same physical location.

Comment: I think that `clflush` is only usable *inside* the kernel. I was talking from the point of view of an application. Don't code inside the kernel if you are not *very* familiar with Linux application code.

Answer (score 0):

While I compile with option -fPIC, I got the same virtual addresses(may be coincidentally)  as well as Physical address same for whole library from both program.

> gcc -fPIC  -o aes openssl_aes.c -lcrypto

This proves that shared library is loaded into same physical location.